# Send DKIM signed mails from PHP?

Tags: php, email, spam-prevention, dkim

I'm currently sending email messages such as password reset emails or confirmations and notifications from my website through [PHP's `mail()` function](http://php.net/manual/function.mail.php).

I'm already specifying `Return-path` and `Reply-to` headers. I'm sending emails like this:

```php
$to = "someone@gmail.com";
$subject = "Hello";
$body = "Blah blah blah";
$from = "rocketnuts@example.com";
$headers = "From: Rocketnuts <$from>\nReturn-path: $from\nReply-to: $from\n";
mail( $to, $subject, $body, $headers, "-f$from" );
```

This works fine, but to reduce the risk of these emails ending up in spam folders, I would like to send **DKIM-signed emails**.

Is this possible with PHP's mail() function, or should I use some 3rd party package? (which?)

When searching around, I see questions like "sending DKIM signed emails to Outlook.com" but I want a *general* solution, not something for specific recipient domains.

Just in case: I'm only sending emails from addresses @ the actual domain where my PHP scripts are running, and I have access to its DNS records.

Comment: Send via SMTP through a *reliable* email provider (such as Google Apps).  You'll never completely win the battle with spam filters unless you do.

Comment: Related: [Setting up DomainKeys/DKIM in a PHP-based SMTP client (closed)](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=php%20dkim%20signed)

Comment: @cale_b Why should that help with preventing a message to be rated as SPAM? The service (system) you send through is irrelevant in that: SPAM filters judge the structure and content of the message and its headers itself, not the forwarding path.

Comment: It helps **a lot**.  Yes, content, headers, etc play a factor, but sending via SMTP overcomes the issue with a no-name, no-trust web server sending e-mails from an IP that might potentially get blocked due to other(s) abusing e-mail from it.

Comment: Have you tried SPF? It's much easier to implement

Comment: @Machavity If by implementing SPF you mean adding a TXT record in my DNS with an appropriate `spf` entry, then yes, I have. When checking through [an external SPF tool](http://mxtoolbox.com/spf.aspx) it says it's valid for my domain.

Comment: I was able to avoid googles junk folders by using ESMTP - both the mail() in PHP from the server (w/ default config) and the mailutils mail command send mail to gmail just fine.  Used a letsencrypt certificate...

Comment: There's a lot more to getting your email to the inbox than DKIM, one of the most important things is having rDNS set up, test your mail using this [eMail Tester](https://www.unlocktheinbox.com/mail-tester/)